# How to open activity page in fragment, when pressed a notification in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I have PushNotificationService and my method onMessageReceived.

If I am in the program, a notification comes from above and directs me to the page I want.

However, when the program is closed, when I click on the notification in the background, it does not go to the page I want, it only goes to the homepage.

And I want to open activity when ı click to notification. How can I do ?

```
public class PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {

        String baslik = message.getNotification().getTitle();
        String icerik = message.getNotification().getBody();
        durumaBagli(baslik,icerik);
        
    }
    private void durumaBagli(String baslik, String icerik) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,BildirimGonder.class);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this,1,intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            String kanalid = "kanalId";
            String kanalAd = "kanalAd";
            String kanalTanim = "kanalTanim";

            int kanalOnceligi = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel kanal = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(kanalid);

            if (kanal == null){
                kanal = new NotificationChannel(kanalid,kanalAd,kanalOnceligi);
                kanal.setDescription(kanalTanim);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(kanal);
            }

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,kanalid);
            builder.setContentTitle(baslik);
            builder.setContentText(icerik);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gurpinarlogom);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setContentTitle(baslik);
            builder.setContentText(icerik);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gurpinarlogom);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
    }
}
```

And my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNav;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                     
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navHostFragment.getNavController());
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#01A2D6")));
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_iletisim:
                Intent mesajGonder = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MesajGonder.class);
                startActivity(mesajGonder);
                Toast.makeText(this, "İletişim sayfası", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This my codes

Answer (score 0):

Put this Flag to your intent like that:

```java
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: It didn't happen, still same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) maybe your FCM type of message does not trigger the `onMessageReceived()` function when the app is in `foreground/background/killed`.

Make sure that the FCM message type is `Data Messages`

Checkout the post as it contain detail about how to setup the FCM correctly so that the notification trigger the `onMessageReceived()` when the application is in `foreground/background/killed`